# WordPress - when removing nav menu item, the linked page is also deleting

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to develop a custom plugin through which I have to add and delete new items to my nav menu.

And I have saved the `term_object_id` from `wp_term_relationships` of each menu tem.

When trying to remove an item from menu it also deleting the linked page ,
I am trying to delete the menu item using the following function,

```
function removeMenuEntry($menu_id,$menuterm){    
     $itemData =  array(
        'menu-item-object-id'   => $menuterm,
        'menu-item-status'      => 'draft'
     );
     wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu_id, $menuterm, $itemData) ;  
}
```

I also tried with the follwing method, but same result,

```
function removeMenuItem($term_menu){
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = " DELETE FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE object_id = '$term_menu' ; ";
    $wpdb->query($sql);
    $sql = " 
    DELETE FROM wp_posts
    WHERE ID=(
    SELECT post_id from wp_postmeta
    WHERE meta_key='_menu_item_object_id'
    AND meta_value='$term_menu'
    ) AND post_type='nav_menu_item' ; ";
    $wpdb->query($sql);
    $sql = " SELECT post_id from wp_postmeta
             WHERE meta_key='_menu_item_object_id'
             AND meta_value='$term_menu' ";
    $result_state = $wpdb->get_results($sql,ARRAY_A);
    $sql = "DELETE from wp_postmeta
            WHERE post_id=".$result_state[0]['post_id']." ";
    $wpdb->query($sql);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working for me. Please check your entire code whether there is another code or function like ,

```
wp_delete_post( );
```

added for deleting the post.

Or try to run the query from your query browser.